# WPF event when a window is no longer on top

Tags: c#, wpf, events, window

I have a WPF window (window1) whose owner is window2.  If a user clicks on window2, or the desktop, or anything else to make window1 not on top of the z-order, I want to set window1's visibility to hidden.  I.e., the window either needs to be on top, or hidden.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();    
    this.Deactivated += new EventHandler(Window1_Deactivated);
}

void Window1_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Note that this will also remove it from the TaskBar.